# How can i get int data from TextEditingController in flutter

Tags: flutter, textfield

i want to get int data entered in the TextField() in flutter, i using TextEditingController:

```
TextEditingController _section_id = new TextEditingController();
```

and using this controller in it:

```
TextField(controller: _section_id,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,)
```

but now, how can i get int data?
i try this way by

```
Repository().placeAddApiProvider(_section_id.text)
```

but its for just string, and try cast to int,

```
Repository().placeAddApiProvider(_section_id.text as int)

 but it is not work show me this error:
Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' in type cast
E/flutter ( 6950): #0      AddPlaceState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:mosul/src/ui/users/add_place.dart:93:50)
E/flutter ( 6950): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 6950): #1      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:513:14)
E/flutter ( 6950): #2      _InkResponseState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:568:30)
E/flutter ( 6950): #3      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestu...
```

Thank you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You cannot cast a `String` to `int` because they do not inherit from the same parent class. You need to parse it instead.

```
Repository().placeAddApiProvider(int.parse(_section_id.text))
```

Comment: int.parse(controller.text) results in an error . Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Invalid number (at character 1)

Comment: Therefore use int.tryParse(controller.text) if int.parse(controller.text) generates an error

Answer (score 19):

Update 2023:

```
int heightValue = int.parse(_heightCon.text);
```

---

when we want to get an integer from TextEditingController do like this,

```
 int var =int.parse(_section_id.text);
```

Answer (score 0):

sometime we want to use tryParse instead for parse.
`int qty=int.tryParse(qtyController.text);`

Answer (score 0):

inside TextField onChanged

```
 onChanged: (s) {
  int s = int.parse(
   _section_id.text);
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

parse string that you get from textfield[Restrict it to enter only digits] to Int and use int.tryParse(String) if you don't worry about the conversion to be successful not or if you do then use int.parse(String)